# Iterator with STL Algorithms and std::execution::par Execution Policy

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl, iterator, c++17

How would one use an Iterator when specifying the `std::execution::par` Execution Policy for an STL algorithm such as `std::for_each`?

In the below example, I wish to take the square root of the diagonal of an Eigen3 Matrix as follows:

```
template<typename T>
using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> getStdDev(const Matrix &x) const {
    const size_t len = x.rows();
    std::vector<T> stdDev(len);

    // Generate indices.
    size_t idx = 0;
    std::vector<size_t> indices(len);
    auto ind = [&idx]() {
        return idx++;
    };
    std::generate(indices.begin(), indices.end(), ind);

    // Take square root of diagonal elements.
    auto sr = [&x](size_t i) {
        stdDev[i] = std::sqrt(x(i, i)); 
    };
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, indices.begin(), indices.end(), sr);

    return stdDev;
}
```

As far as I am aware, the above code is *thread safe*. However, how would one achieve the same effect with an Iterator in a *thread safe* manner without generating the desired indices first, as above? The assumption is that the container to be iterated over does not have an Iterator implemented, or does not have an Iterator that is *thread safe*.

Ideally, I wish to do this generically (I am aware Eigen has Iterators, it is used here just for example purposes).

Additionally, it would be highly preferable to only use C++ features (no libraries, but any non draft standard).

Comment: Ah yes, that part was written in browser. Of course, this should be executed serially. I shall edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [`boost::counting_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) or [`ranges::view::iota`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views)

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> getStdDev(const Matrix &x) const {
    const size_t len = x.rows();
    std::vector<T> stdDev(len);

    // Take square root of diagonal elements.
    auto sr = [&x](size_t i) {
        return std::sqrt(x(i, i)); 
    };
    std::transform(std::execution::par, boost::counting_iterator<int>(0), boost::counting_iterator<int>(len), stdDev.begin(), sr);

    return stdDev;
}
```

Implementing a `counting_iterator` yourself isn't hard, it's just tedious to specify all the required members of [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

```
class counting_iterator
{
public:
    typedef size_t value_type;
    typedef const size_t& reference;
    typedef const size_t* pointer;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    explicit counting_iterator(size_t x);
    size_t const& base() const { return m_inc; }
    reference operator*() const { return m_inc; }
    counting_iterator& operator++() { ++m_inc; return *this; }
    counting_iterator& operator--() { --m_inc; return *this; }

    counting_iterator& operator+=(size_t i) { m_inc += i; return *this; }
    counting_iterator& operator-=(size_t i) { m_inc -= i; return *this; }

    // and loads of others
private:
    size_t m_inc; 
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I am very sorry, I wish not to use any external libraries. I forgot to specify this and shall edit the question accordingly. Sorry again and I do appreciate the answer.

Comment: You can easily write a `counting_iterator` yourself

Comment: To avoid race conditions however I'd have to use atomic operations to update the internal counter, which surely would kill any performance boost gained from parallelisation, right?

Comment: No. Each instance of `counting_iterator` has a separate counter. Iterators are passed by value

Comment: However, I am wondering about potential out-of-order execution. For example if a thread operates on element n, there is no guarantee that the next element is processes will be element n+1. So, I am thinking there would have to be some shared state.

Comment: You don't share any mutable state. You only share const references to the input. Only one thread writes to any given element of the result.

Comment: Each thread operates on a *copy* of the iterators (or however many *copies* it wants to make)

Comment: Ok great, I shall implement a simple Counting Iterator and report back. Thank you.